# Remove item that is inside of an array which is the value in a dictionary Swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I know this might have been answered before, but I couldn't find anything when i searched.

So i have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
var dict = [String:[String]]()
```

What I want to do is to remove a certain index inside of the array (the dictionary's value). Say I want to remove the string "Chair" from this code:

```
dict = ["Furniture": ["Table", "Chair", "Bed"], "Food": ["Pancakes"]]
```

Sorry again if this has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many answers that cover the mutation of dictionary entries tend to focus on the ***remove** value -> mutate value -> replace value* idiom, but note that removal is not a necessity. You can likewise perform an in-place mutation using e.g. optional chaining

```
dict["Furniture"]?.removeAtIndex(1)

print(dict)
    /* ["Furniture": ["Table", "Bed"], 
        "Food": ["Pancakes"]]          */
```

Note however that using the `.removeAtIndex(...)` solution is not entirely safe, unless you perform an array bounds check, making sure that the index for which we attempt to remove an element actually exists.

As a safe in-place-mutation alternative, use the `where` clause of an optional binding statement to check the the index we want to remove is not out of bounds

```
let removeElementAtIndex = 1
if let idxs = dict["Furniture"]?.indices where removeElementAtIndex < idxs.endIndex {
    dict["Furniture"]?.removeAtIndex(removeElementAtIndex)
}
```

Another safe alternative is making use of `advancedBy(_:limit)` to get a safe index to use in `removeAtIndex(...)`.

```
let removeElementAtIndex = 1
if let idxs = dict["Furniture"]?.indices {
    dict["Furniture"]?.removeAtIndex(
        idxs.startIndex.advancedBy(removeElementAtIndex, limit: idxs.endIndex))
}
```

Finally, if using the *remove/mutate/replace* idiom, another safe alternative is using a `flatMap` for the mutating step, removing an element for a given index, if that index exists in the array. E.g., for a generic approach (and `where` clause abuse :)

```
func removeSubArrayElementInDict<T: Hashable, U>(inout dict: [T:[U]], forKey: T, atIndex: Int) {
    guard let value: [U] = dict[forKey] where
        { () -> Bool in dict[forKey] = value
            .enumerate().flatMap{ $0 != atIndex ? $1 : nil }
            return true }()
        else { print("Invalid key"); return }
}

/* Example usage */
var dict = [String:[String]]()
dict = ["Furniture": ["Table", "Chair", "Bed"], "Food": ["Pancakes"]]

removeSubArrayElementInDict(&dict, forKey: "Furniture", atIndex: 1)

print(dict)
    /* ["Furniture": ["Table", "Bed"], 
        "Food": ["Pancakes"]]          */
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkusJohansson happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove specific *element*, you could do this:

```
var dict = ["Furniture": ["Table", "Chair", "Bed"], "Food": ["Pancakes"]]

extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func removeElement(element: Element) {
        if let index = indexOf ({ $0 == element }) {
            removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}

dict["Furniture"]?.removeElement("Chair") //["Furniture": ["Table", "Bed"], "Food": ["Pancakes"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
guard var furniture = dict["Furniture"] else {
    //oh shit, there was no "Furniture" key
}
furniture.removeAtIndex(1)
dict["Furniture"] = furniture
```